# How do I fix the errors in this question?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

The program is running but I'm getting an empty list, and data-frame to excel conversion isn't working.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

l=[]
base_url="https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/Sherman- 
          Oaks_CA/pg-"
for page in range(1,13,1):
    print(base_url+str(page))
    r_1=requests.get(base_url+str(page))
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r_1.content)
    all=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"card-box js-navigate-to js-record- 
        user-activity"})
    for item in all:
        d={}
        try:
            d["Address"]=item.find("span",{"class":"listing-street- 
                         address"}).text.replace(" ","").replace("\n","")
        except:
            d["Address"]=None

        try:
            d["Locality"]=item.find("span",{"class":"listing- 
                          city"}).text+" "+item.find("span", 
                          {"class":"listing-region"}).text+" 
                          "+item.find("span",{"class":"listing- 
                          postal"}).text
        except:
            d["Locality"]=None

        try:
            d["Price"]=item.find("span",{"class":"data-price"}).text
        except:
            d["Price"]=None

        try:
            d["Beds"]=item.find("span",{"class":"data-value meta- 
                      beds"}).text
        except:
            d["Beds"]=None

        try:
            d["Baths"]=item.find("li",{"data-label":"property-meta- 
                       baths"}).find("span",{"class":"data-value"}).text
        except:
            d["Baths"]=None

        try:
            d["Area"]=item.find("li",{"data-label":"property-meta- 
                      sqft"}).text
        except:
            d["Area"]=None

        try:
            d["Lot Size"]=item.find("li",{"data-label":"property-meta- 
                          lotsize"}).text
        except:
            d["Lot Size"]=None
        print(" ")
        l.append(d)

import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(l)

df.to_csv("Real_Estate_list.csv")
df.to_excel("Real_Estate_list.xlsx")
```

I'm supposed to be getting a table with all the values but getting an empty list instead.

As for df.to_excel("Real_Estate_list.xlsx") I'm getting:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'

Comment: try `pip install openpyxl` to fix the `ModuleNotFoundError`

Comment: Have you checked what `all` contains after you assign it with one test page and after trying multiple pages in a loop? I have a suspicion that your `soup` may not contain as much of the page content as you would expect, either because of c\dynamic page loading or the server rejecting your rapid page requests